# Resize Qml window

Tags: c++, qt, qml

In my project I created a transparent and frameless QMainWindow, then created QmlApplicationViewer. I need to be able to drag and resize the window.
How can I do?

Comment: If you created a FRAMELESS window I assume you don't expect to move it around with the mouse cursor, right? So I think you can use [`resize()`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#size-prop).

Comment: I should have been clarified. Yes, I created a frameless window, but only because I do not want to use a standard design.

Comment: Does that mean you want to move the window with the mouse or not? Consider adding the C++ tag.

Comment: Yes, move and resize by mouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This app is a small variation of the one presented here to deal with [transparent windows in QML applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7613672/176769):

**win.cpp:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDeclarativeContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow window;

    QDeclarativeView* v = new QDeclarativeView;
    window.setCentralWidget(v);

    v->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(("draw_rectangles.qml")));   

    // expose window object to QML
    v->rootContext()->setContextProperty("mainwindow",&window);

    window.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");
    window.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    window.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    window.show();

    app.exec();
}
```

**win.pro:**

```
TEMPLATE += app
QT += gui declarative
SOURCES += win.cpp
```

**draw_rectangles.qml:**

```
import Qt 4.7

Item {
     Rectangle {
         opacity: 0.5
         color: "red"
         width: 100; height: 100

         MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: {
                mainwindow.size.width = 200;
                mainwindow.size.height = 500;
            }
         }

         Rectangle {
             color: "blue"
             x: 50; y: 50; width: 100; height: 100

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseRegion
                anchors.fill: parent;
                property variant clickPos: "1,1"

                onPressed: {
                    clickPos  = Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)
                }

                onPositionChanged: {
                    var delta = Qt.point(mouse.x-clickPos.x, mouse.y-clickPos.y)
                    mainwindow.pos = Qt.point(mainwindow.pos.x+delta.x,
                                      mainwindow.pos.y+delta.y)
                }
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Even though you are not interested in transparency, this app shows how to expose `QMainWindow` to QML. This allows the QML application to make changes in the main window.

Click on the **blue rectangle to drag the window around**, and click on the **red rectangle to resize the window** using hardcoded values in the qml. Of course, as the window is transparent you won't have the visual feedback of a regular opaque application when you resize it. But the resize operation works, though. Enjoy!

Comment: I trust you are capable of adapting this code to use `QmlApplicationViewer` instead of `QDeclarativeView`, if you really have to.