# QMainWindow background : transparent not working with Qt4.8

Tags: c++, qt

I was setting QMainwindow background to transparent on CSS file.This was not giving any effect on my mainwindow. If i set background to red or any other color it is getting reflected on my mainwindow.

My mainwindow is transparent while i was working with the Qt4.7.1 version. after updating the qt version to 4.8 with the transparent background property i was getting black background.
I was cross compiled qt4.8 to Mips and i was working on MIPS platform.

Is there any idea on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions about how to create a transparent window:
[How to make a transparent window with Qt Quick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613125/how-to-make-a-transparent-window-with-qt-quick)
[How to get an simple transparent window?](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/1107)
[Transparent Windows.](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/1968)

You can also try to create a new simple empty transparent MainWindow and see if it works correctly. If yes than you should review your project.

Comment: I read all the posts and tried all the possibilities.still i could not done it. as mentioned earlier it was working with Qt4.7 But not working on qt4.8.

Comment: Updated the answer. Maybe this procedure changed in Qt4.8. I will try this out at home.

Comment: In Qt4.8 also except transparent property i can able to set all other colors to my Mainwindow. In my application i was running video on back of my Mainwindow. so i was setting the mainwindow background property to transparent.