# Transparent window isn't transparent

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

[image: Image highlighting corners]

I have a window which should be transparent, then I have popups on top of the window. In the corners you can see a white background.
Tried changing the flags, color etc. to no avail.
Anyone know what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
    import QtQuick 2.15
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
    import QtQuick.Window 2.3
    import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

    Window {
        id: alertsWindow
        width: 750 * scale; height: 500 * scale
        x: Screen.width / 2 - width / 2
        y: Screen.height / 2 - height / 2
        visible: false
        modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
        //    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
        property int alertsData;
        property int eStopData;
        flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground |     Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground
        color: "transparent"
```

Comment: Is this intended to be the top-level window for your application? If not, you probably don't want to use Window (Pane might be a good alternative. If so, you don't want to set x or y - it doesn't make any sense anyway.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613125/how-to-make-a-transparent-window-with-qt-quick

Comment: @mzimmers This is the top-level window.

Comment: @StephenQuan The responses on that post don't work for me hence the new post.